# What is the proper life-cycle of a WCF service client proxy in Silverlight 3?

Tags: wcf, silverlight, wcf-client, wcf-proxy

I'm finding mixed answers to my question out in the web.  To elaborate on the question:

1. Should I instantiate a service client proxy once per asynchronous invocation, or once per Silverlight app?
2. Should I close the service client proxy explicitly (as I do in my ASP.NET MVC application calling WCF services synchronously)?

I've found plenty of bloggers and forum posters out contradicting each other.  Can anyone point to any definitive sources or evidence to answer this once and for all?

Comment: The answer probably depends on your service. Creating the proxy is expensive, but keeping track of that single proxy and managing any errors can be difficult.

Answer (score 3):

I've been using Silverlight with WCF since V2 (working with V4 now), and here's what I've found.  In general, it works very well to open one client and just use that one client for all communications.  And if you're not using the DuplexHttBinding, it also works fine to do just the opposite, to open a new connection each time and then close it when you're done.  And because of how Microsoft has architected the WCF client in Silverlight, you're not going to see much performance difference between keeping one client open all the time vs. creating a new client with each request.  (But if you're creating a new client with each request, make darned sure you're closing it as well.)

Now, if you're using the DuplexHttBinding, i.e., if you want to call methods on the client from the server, it's of course important that you don't close the client with each request.  That's just common sense.  However, what none of the documentation tells you, but which I've found to be absolutely critical, is that if you're using the DuplexHttBinding, you should only ever have one instance of the client open at once.  Otherwise, you're going to run into all sorts of nasty timeout problems that are going to be really, really hard to troubleshoot.  Your life will be dramatically easier if you just have one connection.

The way that I've enforced this in my own code is to run all my connections through a single static DataConnectionManager class that throws an Assert if I try to open a second connection before closing the first.  A few snippets from that class:

```
    private static int clientsOpen;
    public static int ClientsOpen
    {
        get
        {
            return clientsOpen;
        }
        set
        {
            clientsOpen = value;
            Debug.Assert(clientsOpen <= 1, "Bad things seem to happen when there's more than one open client.");
        }
    }

    public static RoomServiceClient GetRoomServiceClient()
    {
        ClientsCreated++;
        ClientsOpen++;
        Logger.LogDebugMessage("Clients created: {0}; Clients open: {1}", ClientsCreated, ClientsOpen);
        return new RoomServiceClient(GetDuplexHttpBinding(), GetDuplexHttpEndpoint());
    }

    public static void TryClientClose(RoomServiceClient client, bool waitForPendingCalls, Action<Exception> callback)
    {
        if (client != null && client.State != CommunicationState.Closed)
        {
            client.CloseCompleted += (sender, e) =>
            {
                ClientsClosed++;
                ClientsOpen--;
                Logger.LogDebugMessage("Clients closed: {0}; Clients open: {1}", ClientsClosed, ClientsOpen);
                if (e.Error != null)
                {
                    Logger.LogDebugMessage(e.Error.Message);
                    client.Abort();
                }
                closingIntentionally = false;
                if (callback != null)
                {
                    callback(e.Error);
                }
            };
            closingIntentionally = true;
            if (waitForPendingCalls)
            {
                WaitForPendingCalls(() => client.CloseAsync());
            }
            else
            {
                client.CloseAsync();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (callback != null)
            {
                callback(null);
            }
        }
    }
```

The annoying part, of course, is if you only have one connection, you need to trap for when that connection closes unintentionally and try to reopen it.  And then you need to reinitialize all the callbacks that your different classes were registered to handle.  It's not really all that difficult, but it's annoying to make sure it's done right.  And of course, automated testing of that part is difficult if not impossible . . .

Answer (score 0):

You should open your client per call and close it immediately after. If you in doubt browse using IE to a SVC file and look at the example they have there.

Comment: What does "immediately after" mean, though, in the world of asynchronous WCF calls used in Silverlight?  Close it after I start the asynchronous call, or close it when completed?  If the latter, it begs the question of what happens if it is never completed.

Answer (score 0):

WCF have configuration settings that tells it how long it should wait for a call to return, my thinking is that when it does not complete in the allowed time the AsyncClose will close it. Therefore call client.AsyncClose().